# family of linear one-step methods, $\delta$-damping

Tags: numerical-methods

This problem follows from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549797/family-of-linear-one-step-methods/1550359#1550359)

Consider the family of linear one-step methods defined by $$y_n = y_{n-1} + h(\theta f_n + (1 - \theta)f_{n-1})$$ where $0\leq \theta \leq 1$.

4) Consider the test problem $y' = \lambda y$, $y(0) = C$. A method is called $\delta$- damping if $$\lim_{\mathcal{R}(h\lambda)\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|y_n|}{|y_{n-1}|}$$ with $0\leq \delta < 1$. For the values of $\theta$ that yield a convergent, write conditions in terms of $\theta$ and $\delta$ that gurantee the methods is $\delta$-damping.

I am not sure how to approach this problem, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert
$$
f_k=λy_k
$$
to get
$$
y_n·(1-θλh)=y_{n−1}·(1+(1−θ)λh).
$$
Then
$$
\frac{y_n}{y_{n-1}}=\frac{1+(1−θ)λh}{1-θλh}\to -\frac{1−θ}{θ}
$$
for $Re(λh)\to-\infty$.

Comment: Could you explain the further steps in the etc part?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the limit formula, I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: Now it looks better.

Comment: I see,  thats what I thought thanks again